# div height overflowing parent div

Tags: html, css

I need the 2 bottom divs to take up the reminder of the height without overflowing past the parent div. if the 2 bottom divs have too much content I would like them to do overflow:scroll and scroll the content of that div. The page should look as if the body has overflow:hidden

html

```
<body>
<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div class="mainHeader">
        header
    </div>
    <div class="mainNav">
        nav
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html{
   height: 100%;
}
body {
   background-color: #69a8ca;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 0 100%;
   margin-top: 2px;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
   height:99%;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.mainWrapper{
   height:100%;
}
.mainNav, .mainContent{
   height: 100%;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.mainHeader{
   display:block;
   text-align:center;
   height: 150px;
   background:red;
}

.mainNav{
   float:left;
   width: 100px;
   background: blue;
}

.mainContent{
   background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dj52b0d7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your current code, apply this CSS:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
background-color: #69a8ca;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 100%;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
height:100vh;
}
.mainWrapper {
height:100%;
}
.mainNav, .mainContent {
height: calc(100vh - 160px);
margin-top: 5px; overflow:auto;
}
.mainHeader {
display:block;
text-align:center;
height: 150px;
background:red;
}
.mainNav {
float:left;
width: 100px;
background: blue;
}
.mainContent {
background: green;
}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wxg1t2zc/)

Comment: This still has a scrollbar on the whole container.  Add `overflow:hidden` to `.mainWrapper`

Comment: yes because it needs the viewport, like <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> and yes, it can use overflow:hidden, but this way he has the whole layout defined in height, no matter if it's 100px height or 1 million pixels, it will be always the same in any screen

Comment: This is pretty close to perfect, but is there a way to remove the little bit of scrolling on the page? The body shouldn't be able to move

Comment: yes sure, add overflow:hidden; to body and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to `.mainWrapper` and add `overflow:auto` to both `.mainNav and`.mainContent`

http://jsfiddle.net/dj52b0d7/1/